# Move GCP point in QGIS Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I can't figure out how to move a GCP in the QGIS Georeferencer.  In the georeferencer I click on the "Move GCP Point" icon and a cross-hairs appears on the map image.  I center the cross-hairs on the point I want to move and left-click, but nothing happens.  Same with right click.  I should also mention that the GCP points are microscopically small on the image.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the "Move GCP Point" tool
- Move the crosshair over the GCP
- Left click - keep button down
- Drag the GCP into new location with the mouse
- Release the button

It often seems like you can't move the GCP, but it's a display scale issue. You need to zoom in enough to be able to click on the point within the tool's tolerance. Then zoom in until you can drag and drop.